# How To Override A WooCommerce AJAX Function

Tags: filters, ajax, callbacks

I would like to override a WP (WooCommerce AJAX function) using add_filter.

The original code is set in a WC OOP class via something like:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_wc_function', array( $this, 'wc_do_stuff' ) );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_wc_function', array( $this, 'wc_do_stuff' ) );
```

And `wc_do_stuff` is a public function.

My question(s):

- What callback would I need to target?
- Is it possible to use add_filter to override an AJAX function; if so, how would I do so?

I've tried (i.e. override *'wc_do_stuff'* with *'my_override_do_stuff'* ...within my custom class):

```
// Tried this, doesn't work
add_filter( 'wc_do_stuff', array( $this, 'my_override_do_stuff' ), 20 );

// And this, also doesn't work
add_filter( 'wc_do_stuff', array('WC_Parent_Class', 'my_override_do_stuff'), 20);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I don't know if this is the best way, but it's working for now.

Within my OOP class (I have a custom plugin to override a WC plugin):

```
    remove_action( 'wp_ajax_wc_function', array( WC_Parent_Class, 'wc_do_stuff' ) );
    remove_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_wc_function', array( WC_Parent_Class, 'wc_do_stuff' ) );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_wc_function', array( __CLASS__, 'my_override_do_stuff' ) );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_wc_function', array( __CLASS__, 'my_override_do_stuff' )
```

Hope this helps someone and I'd welcome/appreciate if anyone has a better method. :)